# Why does deleting a child element from an absolute positioned container affect the scrollTop CSS value of its parent container in CSS?

Tags: html, css, scroll, scrollbar, css-position

`I was trying to understand CSS positions for some project requirements but came across a scenario for which I couldn't find any explanation of why the browser is behaving in a particular way. I was facing this issue in React App but the same issue is happening in pure HTML as well.

Below is a pseudo-code for the problem. I have 4 levels of HTML elements.

```
<parent-container>
  <buffer-container>
    <row-container>
      <row 1 />
      <row 2 />
      <row 3 />
      ....
      <row n />
    </row-container>
  </buffer-container>
</parent-container>
```

parent-container has height given 400px and overflow defined.
buffer-container has position relative and height of 2000px.
row-container has no height, so it takes height based on its children. But it's absolute positioned and the top is given as 0 means the top of buffer-container and row-container align.

Now, when I scroll a bit and on top let's say the 10th row is visible, I go to the devtools Elements tab and delete row 1. The manual deletion is just to simulate the row element getting deleted programmatically. Observe that the scroll bar jumps a bit. The scrollTop CSS value of the parent-container gets changed.

I couldn't understand even if I am deleting rows from row-container which is absolute positioned, why does the deletion causes the scrollTop on parent-container to be changed.

I have prepared a codesandbox to replicate the scenario.
https://codesandbox.io/s/jump-scroll-with-absolute-child-hhg5rg?file=/index.html

I tried going through the CSS issues on Stackoverflow and articles around the CSS positioning but didn't get a proper explanation.`